# Performing a java script calculation mainly subtraction and then addition

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a click event of a button I am getting some values and trying to do 
a calculation.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#SaveTaskChange", function () {

        var EmpHoursOriginal = $("#EmpHoursForCalculation").val();
        var ProdHoursEntered = $("#SelectHours").val();
        var resultReturned = AmIGoodToUpdate(EmpHoursOriginal, ProdHoursEntered);

        if (resultReturned == "donotproceed") {
            $('#status').show();
            $('#status').val("Hours is way too high");
            return false;
        }       
    });
```

As I step through my code and I reach the line below, my code crashes

```
    var Result = parse(TotalKronosHoursEntered) - parse(CurrentHours) + NewHours;
```

Here is the function am using

```
    function AmIGoodToUpdate(CurrentHours, NewHours) {
        var TotalKronosHoursEntered = $('div.lhrs .data').text();
        var HoursPunchedIn = $('div.khrs .data').text();
        var Result = parse(TotalKronosHoursEntered) - parse(CurrentHours) + NewHours;
        if (Result <= HoursPunchedIn)
            return "proceed";
        else {
            return "donotproceed";
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I dont seem to catch it.

Comment: Is `parse()` a function you wrote? It's not in the JS core. `parseFloat()` and `parseInt()` are though.

Comment: You're probably meaning to use `parseInt()`

Comment: I think he means `parseInt(value, 10);`

Comment: Further to j08691's comment: [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) documentation. Incidentally if something's not working it's usually best to try logging the intermediate steps to the console to see where you went wrong, for example: `console.log(parse(TotalKronosHoursEntered))`. (`Uncaught ReferenceError: parse is not defined(…)` in Chrome 54.x/Win10).

Comment: I am doing substraction for numbers with decimal like 8.5000 - 3.5000. I guess this should be float. Thanks

Comment: or Number(CurrentHours);

Comment: Thanks everyone. Parsefloat works very well for me.  I appreciate all your help.